# Regex for checking numbers in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for help with a regex for checking a string that could contain 10 digits separated by other characters or alphabets. For example

```
call1234567890 
1234567890call
12.34_567.890_call
```

I have tried `\D*(\d\D*){10}$` as suggested in other posts , but this matches with any string that has numbers even if 1 and characters after 1. So
Silly_1_me is also being caught

Comment: What would be your expected result given that input? It'd be great if you could [edit] that into your question, just for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must need  to include starting anchor `^` so that it would do an exact line match or otherwise, it would do a partial string match.

```
@"^\D*(\d\D*){10}$"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cG7bP4/1)

For multiline input , its better to use the below regex.

```
@"^[^\n\d]*(\d[^\n\d]*){10}$"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!(?:.*\d){11,})(?:.*\d){10}[^\d]*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/21